# WebLogic server rejecting certain web service requests - seemingly based on SOAP headers

Tags: web-services, soap, weblogic, jax-ws, businessworks

I am developing a simple web service client. I am having issues receiving responses from the server. Since the folks who support the remote server are not cooperative, I would like to learn as much about the problem as possible and hopefully point them in the correct direction.

Given the following details, is it possible to get an idea of what's going on? Are there specific SOAP protocol settings that should be looked at?

I used TcpTrace to capture outbound and inbound traffic.

When I send a request from soapUI, this is the generated SOAP header. This message **succeeds** - I get a valid response.

```
POST /l2/k2/AddressLookup HTTP/1.1 
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: "http://xmlns.test2.com/k2/addressLookup"
User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1
Host: localhost:7003
Content-Length: 434
```

When I send a request from TIBCO BusinessWorks, this is the generated SOAP header. This message **fails** - I get an *HTTP 500 internal server error*.

```
POST /l2/k2/AddressLookup HTTP/1.1
content-type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
SoapAction: "http://xmlns.test2.com/k2/addressLookup"
Connection: close
User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.0.1
Host: localhost:7003
Content-Length: 368
```

When I send a request from a very basic, no-frills JAX-WS client, this is the generated SOAP header. This message also **fails** - I get an *HTTP 500 internal server error*.

```
POST /l2/k2/AddressLookup HTTP/1.1
Content-type: text/xml;charset="utf-8"
Soapaction: "http://xmlns.test2.com/k2/addressLookup"
Accept: text/xml, multipart/related, text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
User-Agent: JAX-WS RI 2.1.6 in JDK 6
Host: localhost:7003
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 389
```

I should note that the Soapaction property was not initially present in the JAX-WS client's SOAP header. Because I thought that might be related to the issue, I added the property via the following code:

```
        dispatch.getRequestContext().put(
            BindingProvider.SOAPACTION_USE_PROPERTY, true);

        dispatch.getRequestContext().put(
            BindingProvider.SOAPACTION_URI_PROPERTY,
            "http://xmlns.test2.com/k2/addressLookup");
```

And finally, here is the error response I receive from the server for both the JAX-WS and TIBCO BusinessWorks requests:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Connection: close
Date: Thu, 19 Jul 2012 14:25:07 GMT
Content-Length: 883
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Encoding: identity
X-Compressed-By: com.planetj.servlet.filter.compression.CompressingFilter/1.7
SOAPAction: ""
X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Draft//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Error 500--Internal Server Error</TITLE>
<META NAME="GENERATOR" CONTENT="WebLogic Server">
</HEAD>
<BODY bgcolor="white">
<FONT FACE=Helvetica><BR CLEAR=all>
<TABLE border=0 cellspacing=5><TR><TD><BR CLEAR=all>
<FONT FACE="Helvetica" COLOR="black" SIZE="3"><H2>Error 500--Internal Server Error</H2>
</FONT></TD></TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE border=0 width=100% cellpadding=10><TR><TD VALIGN=top WIDTH=100% BGCOLOR=white><FONT FACE="Courier New"><FONT FACE="Helvetica" SIZE="3"><H3>From RFC 2068 <i>Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1</i>:</H3>
</FONT><FONT FACE="Helvetica" SIZE="3"><H4>10.5.1 500 Internal Server Error</H4>
</FONT><P><FONT FACE="Courier New">The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.</FONT></P>
</FONT></TD></TR>
</TABLE>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Absolutely any help or insight is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Worth noting - I received successful responses in soapUI when I sent the exact SOAP bodies captured from the JAX-WS and BusinessWorks clients' TCP traffic.

Answer (score 0):

The headers you are showing are the HTTP headers, the SOAP headers (if present) would be in the header section of the SOAP envelope.

What makes you think the problem is related to headers? Could it be the way that the SOAP content is formulated?

I also think it is strange that you get an HTML error response...I would expect a SOAP response containing a FAULT description.